# Slack sidebar automatically collapses: how to keep it permanently open?

Tags: slack

Apparently I hit some shortcut combination that caused Slack to automatically collapse the sidebar that contains the list of Channels and Direct Messages.

[image]

There is an option to **temporarily** show the Sidebar in the View menu:

[image]

we now temporarily see the left sidebar

[image]

But after clicking in conversation area the sidebar will still hide itself again.

[image]

I have looked at Preferences | Sidebar and it does not have any setting related to hide/show:

[image]

Is there any way to do a "factory reset" on  the Slack settings but retain the existing channels? In other words I do not want to completely reinstall Slack unless necessary.

Comment: Have you asked their support?

Comment: What happens if you make the Slack window *wider?" Often apps will expand sidebars when there is more room for them to expand into. Perhaps Slack is like that?

Comment: @SteveChambers ah! pls make that an answer

Comment: In my case, I did have to make the window wider even though it already was rather wide. I had earlier expanded the Thread pane so that was occupying some of the screen real-estate. Personally, I think Slack should offer a standard "pin" icon on the Channels pane and let users decide whether or not they want to always show that pane rather than tie that decision to main-window width--something that has obviously confounded users who can't figure out why the channels pane keeps sliding away...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now a setting for this in the Sidebar Preferences:
[image]

Simply keep that unchecked to prevent the sidebar from collapsing if you shrink the Slack window.

Comment: This is the new correct answer

Comment: This worked for me. In the top left menu bar, click Slack, then click Preferences, then click Sidebar, then scroll down to the bottom and do the above ^

Answer (score 3):

Often time, especially on the web and apps that use macOS to just wrap their web content into a neat package. Just making the window **w i d e r** (if it's a side bar instead of a top/bottom bar) will often make room for the sidebar to expand.

This works on youtube.com and I am wondering if that might be what is going on here as well...

Answer (score 2):

This could also be because of zoom in. I had a similar issue and when used the default (100%) zoom, things worked fine.

You could find zoom option on
top right(your image) -> Preferences -> Accessibility

Comment: `View`->`Actual Size` worked for me on the Windows App.